# onedit trigger: browser.msgbox stops execution

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I need a clarification about an issue I'm encountering.

When using a function fired by an onEdit trigger, it seems that the script stops executing right after the first instance of a Browser.msgBox() command.

Using a code as simple as:

```
function notifyStatus(event)     
    {
      try {

       Browser.msgBox("Message 1!") ;
       Browser.msgBox("Message 2!") ;

      } catch (e) {
        MailApp.sendEmail("myaddress@mydomain", "Bug" , e.message);
      }
    }
```

will bring up the "Message 1!" as expected. But "Message 2!" will never show up and I get no email notification of an error...

Running this in the editor behaves as expected.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

onEdit trigger is a Simple Trigger (unlike installable triggers). onEdit trigger can manipulate spreadsheet related objects. It can not send email.

For details, you may look on below two reference links.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, but my function does send emails succesfully as soon as I remove message boxes. If I have a Browser.msgBox or a Browser.inputBox anywhere before this, it will not occur (as for any other statement occuring after these).

Comment: Btw, I reread the documentation about "understanding triggers": I do use an installable onEdit trigger since the beginning. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just discovered I'm not the only one facing the issue. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2462

Comment: That issue has been merged into [Issue 1728](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1728). Folks should star 1728 if it matters to them.

Answer (score -1):

If I have this Simple trigger function in my script -

```
function onEdit(e) {
  notifyStatus(e);
}
```

Then I see both message boxes. However, if I throw an error in notifyStatus I do not receive an email.

But, if I remove the Simple trigger function and create an installable onEdit trigger for notifyStatus; I see both the message boxes and receive an email. The same is true if I run the script manually.

If you use an installable trigger, the email appears to be sent using the identity of the person who created the trigger. It seems that is not the case when using a Simple trigger.

Comment: see other answer : simple onEdit trigger can't send mails.  Also : why are you asking a question in an answer ? that's not how it is supposed to work on this forum. If you have a question in relation to another one just mention its reference in you own question. thanks

Comment: Serge, I'm not asking a question. I'm stating that I see both messages even with a Simple trigger. Dave said that he did not see the second message. So I agree with Waqar and I'm explaining what I've observed.

Comment: OK, I understand now. It's not the person who creates the spreadsheet that has the problem with message boxes but it's the person with whom the spreadsheet is shared.